# d3 can't recognize data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, svg

in my development work, I meet a very strange problem, please help me

the input is very simple array, but d3 can't recognize the data

> the environment is: Chrome 74 win64, d3-5.9.2

```
let tmpData = [[15.5, 4.8, 0.0, 1.0], [10.18, 4.8, 0.0, 1.0], [1.8, 8.9, 0.0, 1.0], [0, 15, 0.0, 1.0], [0, 22, 0.0, 1.0]]
console.log(typeof tmpData[0][1]) // you can see it's number

let lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x((d) => (d[0]))
  .y((d) => (d[1]))
  .curve(d3.curveLinear)
let tmp = lineGenerator(tmpData)
console.log(tmp)
```

the final output is

```
 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…".
```

but what I want is like

> M15.5,4.8L10.18,4.8L...

then I can bind it to "d" attribute of SVG  element

Comment: It's working correctly for me: https://jsfiddle.net/3bdp5mqy/

Comment: It works fine for me in jsFiddle for version 4 and above, for 3 it spills out errors so maybe check d3 version u have installed and try upgrade or downgrade to see if that isn't the case.

Comment: @Jake11 This is D3 v4 or v5, otherwise OP would have `d3.svg.line()` instead of `d3.line()`. On top of that, there is no `curve` in D3 v3.